# XF app failing on iOS with ReactiveUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

My iOS version of the app used to run until a few weeks ago. I started receiving this error on launch:

[image]

Anyone else ever get this error?

**UPDATE:**

I have RxUI 7.4.0 installed on all platform projects:

[image]

As well, my base viewmodel is as follows:

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel, ISupportsActivation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got to the source of the problem, but I solved this by recreating a new iOS project (simple process for a XF app) and re-adding all the nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what version you're using, but it sounds like you need the [ReactiveUI.XamForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.XamForms/8.0.0-alpha0110) package installed.

Comment: Hi Kent, I do in fact have it installed on all projects (I updated the post). Would you know the meaning of that error?